# Let $A$ and $B$ be $3\times3$ matrices such that their D C T E R M are the same. Then they are similar.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If $A$ and $B$ are $3\times3 matrices such that determinant, characteristic polynomial, trace, eigenvalues, rank and minimal polynomial are the same, then they are similar.

Is it true or false?

Comment: If the characteristic polynomials are the same, then it is automatic that they have the same determinant, trace, eigenvalues, and rank.

Comment: Do you know what the possible Jordan normal forms of a $3 \times 3$ matrix are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices are similar.

A $3\times 3$ matrix has either one Jordan block of size 3 or one block of size 2 and one block of size 1 or three blocks of size 1. In the first case the characteristic polynomial = minimal polynomial $= (\lambda - a)^3$ where $a$ is the only eigenvalue.
This characterizes the matrix up to similarity. So if one of the matrices is such then the matrices are similar.

If it has one block of size 2 with eigenvalue a and one block of size 1 with eigenvalue $b\ne a$ then the characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda-a)^2(\lambda-b)$ which again characterizes the matrix up to similarity.

If $a=b$ then the char polynomial is $(\lambda-a)^3$, the minimal polynomial is $(\lambda-a)^2$, so again the matrix is unique up to similarity.

If there are three blocks of size 1 with eigenvalues $a,b,c$ then if the eigenvalues are all different, the char and min polynomials are $(\lambda-a)(\lambda-b)(\lambda-c)$, and we are done. If two are equal(say, $a=b\ne c$ then the char polynomial is  still $(\lambda-a)(\lambda-a)(\lambda-c)$ but the min polynomial is
$(\lambda-a)(\lambda - c)$ and the matrix is again uniquely defined; finally if $a=b=c$ the minimal polynomial is $\lambda-a$ and we are done.